# C++ STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION when using (non-pointer) reference

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm a newbie to C++ and as a part of my assignment (in subject C++) I have to implement some simplified structures as an Array (similar to class vector) and Heap (similar to class priority_queue) & use them as shown below in the code.

The problem is, that the program exits with STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION, and I'm unnable to figure out why... I've also tried to detect problem using debugger, but everythings seems to works just fine until an error is occured. Could you please help me?

I've tried to simplify the code as mutch as it was possible & marked the problem parts of code by comment.

Thank you for your help.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Array {
protected:
    T* _data;
    int* inst;
    int _size;

public:

    Array() {
        _data = 0;
        inst = 0;
        _size = 0;
    }

    Array(int size) {
        _data = new T[size];
        inst = new int(1);
        this->_size = size;
    }

    Array(const Array& origin) {
        _data = 0;
        inst = 0;
        _size = 0;
        *this = origin;
    }

    /************* Arithmetic operators *************/

    virtual Array& operator=(const Array& origin) {
        if (inst) {
            this->~Array();
        }

        if (inst = origin.inst) {
            _data = origin._data;
            (*inst)++;
            _size = origin._size;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    /************* Member and pointer operators *************/

    virtual inline T& operator[](const int& index) const {
        return _data[index];
    }

    /************* Destructor *************/

    virtual ~Array() {
        if (inst) {
            if (!--(*inst)) {
                delete[] _data;
                delete inst;
            }
            inst = 0;
            _data = 0;
            _size = 0;
        }
    }

};

template<class T, int Comparator(const T& v1, const T& v2)>
class Heap : public Array<T> {
protected:
    int _length = 0;

public:

    Heap() : Array<T>::Array() {

    }

    Heap(const Heap& origin) : Array<T>::Array((Array<T>) origin) {
        _length = origin._length;
    }

    Heap(int size) : Array<T>::Array(size) {
        _length = 0;
    }

    /************* Arithmetic operators *************/

    virtual Heap& operator=(const Heap& origin) {
        Array<T>::operator=((Array<T>) origin);
        _length = origin._length;

        return *this;
    }

    /************* Heap functions *************/

    virtual inline T top() const {
        return (*this)[0];
    }

    virtual Heap& push(T item) {
        int index, parent;

        for (index = _length++; index; index = parent) {
            parent = (index - 1) >> 1;
            if (Comparator(item, (*this)[parent]) >= 0) {
                break;
            }
            (*this)[index] = (*this)[parent];
        }

        // Identified problem part... but why???
        (*this)[index] = item;

        return *this;
    }

    virtual Heap& pop() {
        int index, swap, other;

        T& temp = (*this)[--_length];

        // Reorder the elements
        for (index = 0; 1; index = swap) {
            // Find the child to swap with
            swap = (index << 1) + 1;

            // If there are no children, the heap is reordered
            if (swap >= _length) {
                break;
            }

            other = swap + 1;
            if ((other < _length) && Comparator((*this)[other], (*this)[swap]) < 0) {
                swap = other;
            }

            // If the bigger child is less than or equal to its parent, the heap is reordered
            if (Comparator(temp, (*this)[swap]) <= 0) {
                break;
            }

            (*this)[index] = (*this)[swap];
        }

        (*this)[index] = temp;

        return *this;
    }

};

struct Edge {
    int from;
    int to;
    double cost;

    Edge() {

    }

    Edge(int from, int to, double cost) : from(from), to(to), cost(cost) {

    }
};

int minEdge(const Edge& e1, const Edge& e2) {
    return e1.cost - e2.cost;
}

typedef Heap<Edge, minEdge> EdgeQueue;

int minQueue(const EdgeQueue& eq1, const EdgeQueue& eq2) {
    return eq1.top().cost - eq2.top().cost;
}

typedef Heap<EdgeQueue, minQueue> EdgeQueueQueue;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Array<EdgeQueue> queues(5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        EdgeQueue queue(10);

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            Edge e(i, j, i * j);
            queue.push(e);
        }

        queues[i] = queue;
    }

    EdgeQueueQueue stack(5);

    stack.push(queues[0]);
    stack.pop();

    // So far so good, but this will fail

    stack.push(queues[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Content of stackdump file:

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at rip=00000000000
rax=0000000600042348 rbx=000000000024CAF0 rcx=0000000600042348
rdx=000000000024CA60 rsi=0000000600028390 rdi=0000000000000000
r8 =0000000000000000 r9 =0000000180300400 r10=0000000000250000
r11=00000003FE2B365C r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=000000000024CB61 r15=0000000000000000
rbp=000000000024C980 rsp=000000000024C948
program=C:\Users\Martin\Documents\Skola\PJC\Problem\dist\Debug\Cygwin-Windows\problem.exe, pid 2584, thread main
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame        Function    Args
End of stack trace
```

Comment: Please note, C != C++

Comment: Your `Array` assignment oprator is implemented wrong, you'll share `_data` pointers between instances, and attempt to `delete` them twice.

Comment: Well thats why Array has a property `inst` which count's instances & then `delete` the `_data` only once, when last instance of given Array is destroyed.
Or did I miss something? Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you intend to do so, fix the condition in the ` if (inst = origin.inst)` statement, should be ` if (inst == origin.inst)`, or did you do the assignment intentionally also?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I thought that as well. But it is correct as written. He is doing the assignment and test in a single line. Bad coding practive but valid.

Comment: I can't quite spot the problem. But you are doing things backwards from normal.

Comment: @MartinDendis: We don't put the answer in the question. We put the answer as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this constructor. If the size is zero then the object is left in an undefined state.

```
Array(int size) {
    if (size > 0) {
```

Remember the initial values of POD is indeterminate (ie anything, and its technically UB to read from).

Use the assignment operator in the copy constructor is unique (but valid)

```
Array(const Array& origin) {
    _data = 0;
    inst = 0;
    _size = 0;
    *this = origin;
}
```

Usually we define the assignment operator in terms of the copy constructor using the copy and swap idiom.

You are allowed to call the destructor manually.

```
    if (inst) {
        this->~Array();
    }
```

But you are supposed to call the constructor to reinitialize the object (something to do with lifespans that I will look up). Also you don't check for self assignment. So if you do self assignment you delete the object (which deletes the content) then assign it to itself (which leaves it blank).

Because you have implemented things backwards from normal I can't quite spot the problem. This is what it should look like:

```
template<class T>
class Array {
protected:
    int  size;
    T*   data;
    int* inst;

public:

    virtual ~Array()
    {
        --(*inst);
        if (*inst == 0) {
            delete [] data;
            delete inst;
        }
    }
    Array(std::size_t size = 0)
        : size(size)
        , data(new T[size])        // If this throws no problem.
        , inst(nullptr)
    {
        try {
            inst = new int(1);
        }
        catch(...) {
            delete [] data;  // If we catch the new int(1) failed.
            throw;           // We need to release the data and
        }                    // and allow the exception to propagate.
    }

    Array(Array const& origin)
        : size(origin.size)
        , data(origin.data)
        , inst(origin.inst)
    {
        ++(*inst);
    }

    virtual Array& operator=(Array origin) // Copy and Swap idium
    {
        origin.swap(*this);
    }

    void swap(Array& other) noexcept
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(size, other.size);
        swap(data, other.data);
        swap(inst, other.inst);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for help, for now it seems that the problem was in calling destructor manually and not re-initializing the object after that.
I'll perform some more tests & post the result, but for now it seems to be fixed.